# Can I prevent instantiation of a certian type, except through a helper class? With Resharper or StyleCop perhapse?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, httpcookie

After a security audit, I'm trying to enforce the creation of secure HttpCookies in our MVC app. I came up with a helper class to create them:

```
public static class CookieHelper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Create Cookie.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">Cookie name.</param>
    /// <param name="value">Cookie value.</param>
    /// <returns>A cookie.</returns>
    public static HttpCookie CreateSecureCookie(string name, string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
        }

        var cookie = new HttpCookie(name, value);

        cookie.Secure = true;

        return cookie;
    }
}
```

I hooked into this where we're currently creating cookies so we're okay now. But, we're a growing organization and many folks will be working the code base, so I'm a little concerned about folks creating new cookies outside of this helper class in the future.

Is there a way I can setup a rule in Resharper, StyleCop, or anything else that prevents instantiation of a new HttpCookie(), except in the helper class?

Comment: you could put the CookieHelper and the HttpCookie in a own assembly and mark the HttpCookie private. So if someone wants to use it you have to reference that assembly and can only access it via the Helper, as long as they dont implement in that assembly

Comment: @derape - `HttpCookie` is part of `System.Web`.

Comment: @Levitikon - Code reviews should catch somebody not using your wrapper class.

Comment: Or you could probably quite easly create `StyleCop` rule to report that and then easly catch this in CI. Won't prevent instantiation, but you will know right away when someone will do this and will be able to fix and discuss this

Comment: Thanks @Pako, That should do the trick!

Comment: You could use the Factory pattern. However I personally feel that coding reviews and standards should handle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

When building your own class, you can prevent access by making the constructor private (or internal). But when you're dealing with an existing class provided from somewhere else (like the BCL), you have to work with what's allowed.

Your best bet here to enforce secure cookies it to build an architecture at a higher level that accepts a `SecureCookie` or `IEnumerable<SecureCookie>` as an argument to a required function.